# llinux - replace subnet mask in ifcfg-eth0 with sed or awk

Tags: linux, centos, bash, scripting, sed

I have 30 linux servers that I need to change subnetmask. I want to use a simple script or a simple command to change the subnemt mask from 255.255.255.128 to  255.255.255.0 in ifcfg-eth0.

can someone please help?
Thanks,
Elad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `sed` command like this will do it:

```
$ sudo sed -i 's/NETMASK=255.255.255.0/NETMASK=255.255.255.128/' /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

You can combine this `sed` command with SSH command to execute this on each server using the a command like:

```
$ ssh user@server command
```

Comment: A simple for loop + SSH key-based authentication should make it automatic to change files on all machine, but you need to do another command to restart the network service for the changes to take effect.